# Animated patches in ArtistAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch, matplotlib-animation

Due to the code structure I cannot use FuncAnimation where I can make paches moving.

Is there a way to include animated patches into ArtistAnimation? In the following two samples I took the tutorial code from [animation_tutorial.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/animation_tutorial.html) and tried to include animated rectangle which identifies the current maximum. They either do show only the last position of the patch or no patch at all. The code is made to display the animation under Jupyter/Google Colab (see the last line of both examples).

```
# version A
# intention: include patches in ArtistAnimation
# problem: only the last position of the patch is shown during the animation

from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np      

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rng = np.random.default_rng(19680801)
data = np.array([20, 20, 20, 20])
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
c = plt.Rectangle(xy=[0,0], width=10, height=1, edgecolor="black", facecolor="white")
ax.add_patch(c)


artists = []
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:green', 'tab:purple']
for i in range(20):
    data += rng.integers(low=0, high=10, size=data.shape)
    mm = max(data)
    i_max = list(data).index(mm)
    c.xy=[mm-5,i_max+0.5]
    container = ax.barh(x, data, color=colors)
    artists.append(container)


anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig=fig, artists=artists, interval=400)
plt.close()

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

or

```
# Version B
# intention: include patches in ArtistAnimation
# problem: no patch is shown during the animation

from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np      

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rng = np.random.default_rng(19680801)
data = np.array([20, 20, 20, 20])
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])


artists = []
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:green', 'tab:purple']
for i in range(20):
    data += rng.integers(low=0, high=10, size=data.shape)
    mm = max(data)
    i_max = list(data).index(mm)
    c = plt.Rectangle(xy=[mm-5,i_max+0.5], width=10, height=1, edgecolor="black", facecolor="white")
    ax.add_patch(c)
    container = ax.barh(x, data, color=colors)
    artists.append(container)
    c.remove()


anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig=fig, artists=artists, interval=400)
plt.close()

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```